# Python3.3 SublimeText3 subprocess for node command

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, sublimetext3

This is weird since the behavior is broken since I updated myOS from OSX MountainLion to Mavericks(DeveloperPreview5.1)

I use **subprocess** function in **Python3.3** in **SublimeText3** plugin code.
Here, subprocess Popen [node](http://nodejs.org)

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['node', '-v'],
        shell=False,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )
```

Obviously, I already installed node with [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm%E2%80%8E), and since this code runs in context of `/Applications/`, so I tested `node -v` command surely works with Path setting on zsh and bash.

In fact, I thoroughly tested the code on OSX MountainLion, so thought it's nothing wrong; however, yesterday, I upgraded OSX to Mavericks(DeveloperPreview5.1), and found an error with the code.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'node'
```

To make sure I've modified the code to

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['git', '--version'],
        shell=False,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )
```

and this time, I see the expected result of  `git --version`.

So, obviously, I think `node` path is somehow not recognized by python3.3 in SublimeText3 context, but I made sure the path is working under bash/zsh.

Nothing I can do more except to ask here. Please advise. Thanks.

**EDIT:** I think this is due to a path detection bug of python3.3 + OSX Maverics

When I give a full path of node, it works.

Comment: What happend when you specify `shell=True` instead of `shell=False`?

Comment: b'-v: node: command not found\n' ... @falsetru

Comment: Then, try `p = subprocess.Popen('node -v', shell=True, ....)`

Comment: no can do. I also did ```subprocess.call('node -v', shell=True)```, this is really bad..  No errors occur in this case, just silently fails.

Comment: I got the same problem and I think it's caused by nvm because I use `nvm use node stable` in my `.bash_profile`. So it works in the terminal but not in sublime plugin.